# How to build OpenBLAS on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, linear-algebra

I am attempting to build OpenBLAS (http://www.openblas.net/) on OSX Mavericks

Just typing 'make', it hits an error several minutes into the make process.

I've scoured the Internet for solutions, yielding a handful of commandline parameter suggestions such as:

```
make CC=clang
make MD5SUM='md5 -q'
make MD5SUM='md5 -q' CC=clang
make MD5SUM='md5 -q' CC=clang FC=/Users/pi/Downloads/usr/local/bin/gfortran DYNAMIC_ARCH=1
make MD5SUM='md5 -q' CC=clang FC=/Users/pi/Downloads/usr/local/bin/gfortran DYNAMIC_ARCH=1 USE_THREAD=1 NO_SHARED=1
```

None of which work.

Is anybody able to get this library to build without errors?

Links: 
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/334
http://yurii-aulchenko.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/building-openblas-for-mac-os-x-1075-lion.html

Here is the error for the last attempt in the list above:

```
ar -ru ../../../libopenblasp-r0.2.9.rc1.a 
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[3]: *** [../../../libopenblasp-r0.2.9.rc1.a] Error 1
make[2]: *** [lapacke] Error 2
make[1]: *** [lapackelib] Error 2
make: *** [netlib] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like a broken makefile; I don't see why this would be OSX-specific.

Comment: I'm having the same issues.  I had no trouble making it under 10.8, and now it's broken on 10.9.  There must be a make file issues with 10.9, maybe open a bug on the github repository?

Comment: I did get it working in the end by installing it via Homebrew: http://mathpad.wikidot.com/acousto

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
brew install openblas
```

gives you

```
Error: No available formula for openblas
Searching taps...
homebrew/science/openblas
```

so you

```
brew install homebrew/science/openblas
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commits/master/openblas.rb

Comment: In 2016, `brew install homebrew/science/openblas` gives `Cannot tap homebrew/science: invalid syntax in tap!` on OSX :/

Comment: Hmm, we must have different brew versions, because I just got the error again! I ended up compiling from source :)

Comment: Had the same error, then ran `brew update` and it worked fine

Comment: Any success on Catalina? Gives `Error: homebrew/science was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.`